# Find commas in text string

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to find , where they occur within any ' string '. I tried `#'([[^'],])*'#` but this didn't work. What's the simplest way to achieve this so I can replace them. Thanks.

Example:

```
$str = "(1,2132,'hello world 1, (this is to force it) & another, comma')";

$value_str = preg_replace("#'([[^'],])*'#",'C_1',$str);
```

Expected output:

```
'hello world 1C_1 (this is to force it) & anotherC_1 comma'
```

Comment: `(,)`  - but really a string replace would be less overhead (instead of regex) https://regex101.com/r/vB6vX0/1

Comment: post a long example along with expected output.

Comment: for just finding a single character in a string, pretty much whatever language you use will have a built in function for this

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I would hope for 'hello world 1C_1 (this is to force it) & anotherC_1 comma'

Comment: @Antony provide the exact expected output.

Comment: @runDOSrun `str_replace` will replace all the commas.

Comment: @Antony Do you have to do it in a single replace? How about first getting the text between single quotes, then replace the commas there?

Comment: @runDOSrun he don't want to touch the commas which are present outside the quotes.

Comment: @Jerry - yes not a bad idea. I had expected it to be easier through regex. Also I don't believe this question is a duplicate as this is <i>inside</i> quotes not outside.

Comment: @Antony Is that easier? http://ideone.com/4EZ6W5

Comment: @Jerry - yes it probably is. Question though - is it more efficient to do it all in 1 single call like the preg_replace or is it better to do a find, loop, replace? I had expected the pattern to be quite easy but I'm not sure how slower the answer pattern would be v the foreach you've suggested.

Comment: @Antony The lookahead that the single regex uses is usually expensive. It  goes forward then comes back at its initial point many times; might as just consider it as a long loop. And if you have many text between quotes, a callback might be more efficient (so you use a single function instead of looping to get all the text between quotes): [updated](http://ideone.com/3CRbAR). (also, I'm not sure if you want the original text back or only the quoted text....)

Comment: @Jerry - thanks. I will actually use your code because I also need to tackle ( ) in a string which makes sense doing it in chunks like that. I'm trying to parse a mysql insert statement which may or may not have multiple value parts.

Comment: @Antony Ok cool. Glad I could help :). If you want to replace both at the same time, you can simply change the regex in the code from `"#'[^']*'#"` to `"#'[^']+'|\([^()]+\)#"` though you will need to be careful around nested parens. This regex takes only parens without nested ones, a regex that does will take the complexity up by quite a level (and speed will suffer accordingly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
$str = "(1,2132,'hello world 1, (this is to force it) & another, comma')";
$value_str = preg_replace("#(?!(([^']*'){2})*[^']*$),#", 'C_1', $str);
//=> (1,2132,'hello world 1C_1 (this is to force it) & anotherC_1 comma')
```

`(?!(([^']*'){2})*[^']*$)` is a lookahead that makes sure comma is *not* followed by even number of single quotes.

Comment: Perfect - yes you can. I'm surprised it wasn't simpler but thanks!